# ggvis fill attribute is not working for certain layers or variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

Pretty straightforward:

1. This does not work

   ```
   iris %>%  
   ggvis(x= ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, fill=~Sepal.Length) %>%
   layer_bars()
   ```
2. This it does

   ```
   iris %>%  
   ggvis(x= ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, fill=~Sepal.Length) %>% 
   layer_points()
   ```

Why?

I actually managed to use the fill aesthetic with another dataset that I am not sharing, but that's just to point out that the fill should definitely work in my replicable example, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?layer_bars`

> If grouping var is continuous, you need to manually specify grouping

```
iris %>%  
  group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
  ggvis(x= ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, fill = ~Sepal.Length) %>%
  layer_bars()
```

Which gives:

[image]